# Water fountain in Europe with jagged sculpture

Tags: europe, identify-this, parks-and-gardens

Does anyone recognize this water fountain in Europe? Best guess is Romania, could be wrong.
[image: fountain behind a blocked out person]

Comment: That "jagged sculpture" just looks like someone has been removed from the photo.  If you look at the shadow falling on the concrete you can see two "legs".  In addition the coloration of the "sculpture" is too dark, flat and consistent to be an image of something in real life.  And I just looked at the black part.  It has an RGB value of 0x000

Comment: @PeterM OP obviously refers to the jagged stone sculpture in the middle of the fountain. The stone is covered with jagged peaks ment to resemble mountain summits in the Alps.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo D'oh. The way the question is written, I took jagged sculpture and water fountain to be separate objects.  If the OP had said "jagged water fountain", then I would hav elope beyond the "jagged sculpture"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless there is a very similar place somewhere in Romania, the fountain you have a picture of there is not in Romania, but is the Fontana delle Alpi in Verona, Italy.

Here is the fountain seen from approximately the same angle on Google Maps:

https://www.google.de/maps/@45.4384722,10.9926887,3a,75y,44.72h,89t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1soovRLNgjnSlL5q0iWP-LOw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: Quite the rescue for a question with 5 downvotes!

Comment: @Relaxed I honestly don't understand the down-votes here. Even if OP assumed that the fountain was somewhere in Romania, this was one of the better 'where is this'-questions we have had here and a fairly easily recognizable location. Although in this case, a Google image search would probably have solved the question as well.

Comment: This is a) not a good question for this site, as it doesn't meet our "valuable to future visitors" requirement. Also, see https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8473/1381